# Pivot Parcela (Linha em coluna)

Tags: sql-server, tsql

Senhores, bom dia !

Eu estou tentando fazer um PIVOT simples de parcela sob mesmo numero do cliente (330162210001), porem nao estou conseguindo...

A ideia é que a cada resultado de parcela encontrado seja uma coluna.

Ja tentamos diversos aggregation function sql, porem sem êxito.

Esta dando este erro :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentamos converter todos os tipos de type possivel para que ele consiga fazer a leitura. Mas sem êxito.

Type da Tabela que estamos trabalhando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado da Subquery:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Code utilizado:

```
SELECT * FROM (             
              SELECT dup.cliente, dup.VR_LIQ_ATU,dup.NUMERO, DUP.VALOR             
              FROM DUPLICATAS_ABERTAS DUP WHERE dup.CLIENTE = 330162210001) as Q 
PIVOT(     
       MAX (cliente)        
       FOR VR_LIQ_ATU IN ([VALOR_C]))AS PVT
```

Se alguem conseguir dar uma luz, Agradecemos a compreensão.

Comment: O que seria esse "VALOR_C"? Não vi ele presente/declarado na SQL. Outra dúvida é, se tiver 1000 linhas, ele transformará essas 1000 linhas em 1000 colunas? Ou há um limite de retornos por cliente, por exemplo, terá no máximo 12 parcelas.

Comment: pedro o valor_c é só a coluna que ele tem que retornar o dado da parcela. Nessa tabela no entra até 3 parcelas. Entao não preciso me preocupar com isso sabe? rs

Comment: na verdade o PIVOT, pelo menos no SQL Server não funciona assim, o campo que fica ali no IN é o identificador da coluna pivotada. Vou colocar como resposta pra você entender melhor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maguim,
conforme mencionei no comentário, o que fica dentro do IN é o identificador da coluna pivotada, pra você entender melhor, ele deve ser o elemento que consta na linha. Pelos dados fornecidos, daria para montar assim (pode haver outras formas, mas não sei como está a arquitetura do seu banco em relação aos campos):

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CLIENTE ORDER BY CLIENTE) AS ORDEM,
    DUP.CLIENTE, 
    DUP.VR_LIQ_ATU, 
    DUP.NUMERO
    --DUP.VALOR 
    FROM TESTE DUP 
    --WHERE DUP.CLIENTE = 3301
) AS Q 
PIVOT(SUM(VR_LIQ_ATU) FOR ORDEM IN ([1], [2], [3]) )AS PVT
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

outros scripts:

```
--CREATE TABLE TESTE (
--CLIENTE VARCHAR(100),
--VR_LIQ_ATU NUMERIC(10,4),
--NUMERO VARCHAR(100),
--VALOR VARCHAR(100)
--);

--INSERT INTO TESTE VALUES (3301, 173.55, 62, 'R$ 177,59' )
--INSERT INTO TESTE VALUES (3301, 1395.55, 62, 'R$ 1395,59' )
--INSERT INTO TESTE VALUES (3301, 1455.55, 62, 'R$ 1455,59' )
--INSERT INTO TESTE VALUES (3302, 152.55, 62, 'R$ 152,59' )
--INSERT INTO TESTE VALUES (3302, 11.55, 62, 'R$ 11,59' )
--INSERT INTO TESTE VALUES (3303, 1365.55, 62, 'R$ 1365,59' )
--INSERT INTO TESTE VALUES (3303, 188.55, 62, 'R$ 188,59' )
```

Comment: pedro ! obg meu amigo, ficou mais claro agr. abraços.

Comment: Se a resposta te ajudou ou resolveu o seu problema, não esqueça de dar um voto ou selecionar como resposta para a pergunta, assim ajudará outros que tiverem o mesmo problema.